# How to I launch a view controller from a tap gesture

Tags: xcode, storyboard, mkmapview, coordinates, uigesturerecognizer

Apologies if this is a basic question but I am new to Xcode and have a storyboard app and in the storyboard (with no segue) I have a view controller with an embedded map view.

On the storyboard screen I have an image with a tap gesture linked, I have tested the tap and it works (NSLog) but I want to know how to launch my mapview view controller and also zoom to an x&y.

My code currently has

```
-(IBAction)handleMapTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {   
    NSLog(@"Tapped");  
 }
```

& I have tried;

```
MMMapViewController *mapViewController = [[MMMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
```

My view controller has a class set as MMMapViewController I have given the view controller a storyboard id of MapView (if it's required?).

I've read a lot of stackoverflow articles but can't seem to find an answer. If anyone can help I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)handleMapTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    MMMapViewController *mapViewController = [[MMMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
     [self presentModalViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
    [mapViewController release];
}
```

It would probably help to know what self is, if it is indeed a UIViewController, then 
I would make sure that self.navigationController is not nil.
You actually have the right code, as far as I can tell, but depending on your scenario, you could get away with presenting the mapView as a modal view controller.

Comment: Thank you, I carried on playing and worked out how to segue across to the map view, what I now need to do is to zoom in on the a defined location, but that's tomorrows task! Thanks again.